# Change <s:textfield name="catbean.categorycode" label="Category Code " size="15" /> label color in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-html

I am new to struts. How to change the label color for textfield?

Ex:

I want to change the color of 'Category Code'.I tried cssstyle="color: #ffffff" . But this changed the color only for text entering in textbox, not for the label .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:label value="Username" cssStyle="color: #ffffff;"/>
<s:textfield name="username" required="true" cssStyle="color:red"/>
```